# ClearML get max value from logged values

Tags: devops, clearml, trains

I use ClearML to track my tensorboard logs (from PyTorch Lightning) during training.
At a point later I start another script which connects to existing task and do some testing.

But unfortenautly I do not have all information in the second script, so I want to query them from the logged values from ClearML server.

How would I do this?

I thought about something like this, but havn't found anything in documentation:

```
task = Task.init(project_name="Project", task_name="name", reuse_last_task_id="Task_id, continue_last_task=True)
x_value, y_value = task.get_value(key="val/acc", mode="max")
x_value2, y_value2 = task.get_value(key="epoch", mode="x", x=x_value)
```

- `x_value` would be my epoch or global step
- `y_value` the maximum value of plot "val/acc"
- `x_value2` would be my epoch or global step
- `y_value2` the value of plot "epoch" at `x_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer I'm part of the ClearML (formerly Trains) team.

To get an existing `Task` object for a running (or completed/failed) experiment, assuming we know Task ID:

```py
another_task = Task.get_task(task_id='aabbcc')
```

If we only know the Task project/name

```py
another_task = Task.get_task(project_name='the project', task_name='the name')
```

Notice that if you have multiple task under the same name it will return the most updated one.
Once we have the `Task` object, we can do:

```py
latest_scalar_values_dict = another_task.get_last_scalar_metrics()
```

Which would return all the scalars min/maxm/last values, for example:

```
latest_scalar_values_dict = {
            'title': {
                'series': {
                    'last': 0.5,
                    'min': 0.1,
                    'max': 0.9
                    }
                }
            }
```

[documentation here](https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/rst/references/clearml_python_ref/task_module/task_task.html?highlight=get%20metrics#clearml.task.Task.get_last_scalar_metrics)

If you need to get the entire graphs you can use `task.get_reported_scalars()` [see docs](https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/rst/references/clearml_python_ref/task_module/task_task.html?highlight=get_reported_scalars#clearml.task.Task.get_reported_scalars)